# Matrix of a linear map Questions

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $n < m$. Show there exists a basis $w_1,\dots,w_m$ of $w$ for every choice of basis for $v$ of degree $n$ such that the last $m-n$ rows of $M(T)$ consist of only $0$'s for every choice of basis for $w$.

Note: $T$ is some linear transformation from $F^n$ to $F^m$, or from $V$ to $W$.

At first I was thinking that $w$ could be a basis that takes each $w$ and adds $m-n$ $0's$ to the end so that you get vectors in $F^m$, but that wouldn't be linearly independent since it contains zeros. Then I tried to figure out a way to use the elements from the basis of $V$ so that they always vanish at the last $m-n$ points, but again I could not figure out a way to do this so that $W$ would be linearly independent. Any help?

Comment: Some linear transformation from $F^n$ to $F^m$, ell edit the question.

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear. What quantifier is placed before the basis $w_1,\dots,w_n$? First you say 'there exists' then 'for every choice of basis'...

Comment: Sorry I was really tired when I typed this out I think I fixed everything now.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: take a basis in the range (image) of $T$ (often written as $\ {\rm im\,}T$ or $\ {\rm ran\,}T$), and extend it to a basis of $F^m$.

Comment: the range of T is in $F^m$ though, I don't understand sorry?